# Freelance site with lowest commission fees?

Tags: fees, job-offer, commission

I got a gig from one of the company via email & interviews and they made me a good offer.

They want me to start this collaboration via `Elance` and when I looked at the fees/charges on Elance I found `8.75%` of the project fees to be on a higher side. I had a discussion with the company folks and they said they are open to other alternatives as well.

So, are there any other alternatives for this type of collaboration without involving any freelance websites and if not any alternative to Elance which are safe & has low charges.

Answer (score 0):

Your own site/business.

I’m in freelancing and internet business for 15 years, 20 years IT experience.
Currently i use freelance websites for cheap Asian employees, very seldom for EU/USA employees, and if only if local competition is heavily out-pricing qualified staff.

Till I went "limited" i.e., founded a limited corporation I was jobbing as freelancer and sole proprietor, both with limited success due to the strong Asian competition i myself currently hire. The point where freelancing got "not sustainable" as primary income was 2006 for me, don’t want to get into detail but every freelancer who was active back then knows what I mean, it was like whole India got internet.

If you have absolutely no references, do it for the references a limited time and see the fee you pay as service for you to get references, then start your own web identity, either as freelancer or as corporation. Make sure you take your very satisfied customers with you. Every "very satisfied" customer in your contact list means 10 new customers which mean 2 new customers which mean 0.2 new customers and so on.

Honestly, this info is solely based on experience of this niche fro ma European citizen perspective, if you’re based anywhere else the situation might be totally different.